# how export a table of database postgres to a csv with qt?

Tags: sql, postgresql, qt

Already has the connection succesful. 
With qtsqlquery. Seem imposible execute the copy sentence of the postgresql. 
For example:
execute this query on qt:

```
COPY table TO 'D:/table.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: Please include a code example in your question to show us what exactly you are trying and where it goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

After study a little bit, found a script on the folder of installation of PostgreSQL (.../scripts), then modified the script to executed the command COPY TO. Because the QSQLQUERY Definitely don't executed the command COPY. Here are the Script on win7.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('chcp ^|find /c "932"') do @ SET CLIENTENCODING_JP=%%a
if "%CLIENTENCODING_JP%"=="1" SET PGCLIENTENCODING=SJIS
if "%CLIENTENCODING_JP%"=="1" SET /P PGCLIENTENCODING="Client Encoding [%PGCLIENTENCODING%]: "

REM Run psql
"D:/PostgreSQL\bin\psql.exe" -h localhost -U USER -d DATABASE -p 5432 --no-password --command="\copy (select * from TABLE) TO './EXPORT_TABLE.csv' CSV HEADER"
```